# better to be had but wasn't meant to be on the day!

Tags: meaning

I came across the comment below while reading the comments section of this Youtube video (link below) of several cars and a bike racing each other. The comment in question seems to be pointing out that the bike's clutch was slipping, but I'm not sure what the rest of it means. I thought "better to be had" was some kind of idiom and tried looking it up on Google but it didn't give me any valuable information. Could anyone explain this to me? Thank you.

> Sounds like the clutch was slipping the whole time as well definitely
> **better to be had but wasn't meant to be on the day!**
>
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SmVana9JPFc

Comment: "comments section of this Youtube video"  Not always a source of well written grammatical English...

Answer (score 2):

As written it is an ungrammatical word soup.

The idiom "it wasn't meant to be" is an expression which people use when talking to someone who has lost a race or other competition. "On the day" suggests that he might be successful on another day. So this means that the driver "had bad luck and a bad day" but "should do better next time".

Much of the rest appears just to be a jumble of words with no obvious structure.

Comment: Your explanation makes a lot of sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'd define this as [**stream of consciousness***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_of_consciousness), where the writer has more ideas than time, or ability, to shape them properly, or even insert any punctuation; and as is so often the case, is completely unaware that they failed to transmit their thoughts so others could extract the meaning without having to read it six times, inserting different 'invisible commas', until one interpretation starts to make vague sense.

You could break it down into three ideas.

- Mechanical issue.
- Could do better next time, without the issue.
- Had no chance of winning today, because of the issue.

You can consider 'meant to be' in this case as '[destined](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/destined)' - controlled by fate, not by humans.

*Stream of consciousness can be a clever writing style or, as in this case, barely better than [word salad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_salad).

Inserting punctuation helps a bit, but you still need to know the meanings of 'better to be had', 'meant to be' and 'on the day', which are all sports clichés frequently used by commentators who need to keep talking constantly, and so have an arsenal of these stock phrases they use to fill time & save having to think of new ways to say things.

> Sounds like the clutch was slipping the whole time, as well.
> Definitely better to be had; but wasn't meant to be on the day.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. It's so clear now.